# Wordpress single post navigation and get_adjacent_post

Tags: php, wordpress

In a single post navigation I made for a blog, I'm looking to get the previous and the next post ID to display the title and get the permalink.

I tried `get_adjacent_post()` and `get_previous_post() / get_next_post()` but there is no way to get any info about it… (`<?php print_r($prev) ?>` returns blank)

I just have a **index.php** file with this code:

```
if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   $prev = get_adjacent_post(false, "", true);
   $next = get_adjacent_post(false, "", false);

   <ul>
      <li id="prev">
         <?php //if (!empty($prev)) : ?>
            <a href="<?= get_permalink($prev->ID) ?>">
               <div>
                 <time datetime="<?= get_the_date("Y-m-i", $prev->ID) ?>"><?= get_the_date("j F", $prev->ID) ?></time>
                 <span><i></i></span>
              </div>
           </a>
           <?php //endif ?>
        </li>
        <li class="center"></li>
        <li id="next">
           <?php //if (!empty($next)) : ?>
           <a href="<?= get_permalink($next->ID) ?>">
              <div>
                 <time datetime="<?= get_the_date("Y-m-i", $next->ID) ?>"><?= get_the_date("j F", $next->ID) ?></time>
                 <span><i></i></span>
              </div>
           </a>
           <?php //endif ?>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: What error do you have with your code ?

Comment: My `print_r($prev)` just returns me nothing…

Comment: What about next? To be sure you aren't viewing the newest post right?

Comment: next is the same! I tested to see on the homepage and on a single page, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woooookay. Because of a I-don't-know-why, I deactivated the "category" taxonomy, so it broken these functions…
Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a `:` between the `if` and `while` statements

`if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

Comment: hm I don't think so, "the loop" works without a `:` in the `if`. (well it always works with all my templates)